# Red5 Installed but Connection Failing

Tags: java, ant, streaming, red5

I am managing to install Red5 onto my VPS (I can tell it worked from looking up the IP/5080) but when it comes to testing, I get a connection failed error.

I am using terminal on mac for entering commands and cyberduck for accessing the directories/ftp.

I install java & ant, open ports 1935 and 5080 along with Red5 itself.

The problem could be to do with using certain versions but I really don't know after so many attempts to get this connected.

I've attempted to use several tutorials out there, but the commands don't work so I've only been able to narrow down the sources to use.

URL used for installing Red5 w/tutorial: http://www.muktware.io/setup-red5-streaming-media-server/

This source worked for me flawlessly but it doesn't connect, it's the only source I've followed the commands where it created and installed/started up the red5 application.

URL I found useful for further testing: http://blog.svnlabs.com/install-red5-1-0-1-on-centos-release-6-5-final-64-bit/

The second URL helped me because it helped me open ports, install ant which the first one didn't along with exporting paths etc.

Error I receive when testing connection with OFLA demo on Red5:

```
(110) Connections: true | true
(12643) connected?: true
(12911) NetConnection.onStatus: 
  data = 
      version = 4,0,0,1121
      type = red5

  fmsVer = RED5/1,0,5,0
  capabilities = 33
  mode = 1
  description = Connection succeeded.
  code = NetConnection.Connect.Success
  level = status


(12914) catchVideos: [type Function]
(12976) NetConnection.onStatus: 
  stacktrace = org.red5.server.service.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:106),org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler.invokeCall(RTMPHandler.java:186),org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler.onCommand(RTMPHandler.java:293),org.red5.server.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPHandler.messageReceived(BaseRTMPHandler.java:105),org.red5.server.net.rtmp.ReceivedMessageTask.call(ReceivedMessageTask.java:57),org.red5.server.net.rtmp.ReceivedMessageTask.call(ReceivedMessageTask.java:11),java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266),java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511),java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266),java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142),java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
      11 = java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
      10 = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      9 = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      8 = java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      7 = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
      6 = java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      5 = org.red5.server.net.rtmp.ReceivedMessageTask.call(ReceivedMessageTask.java:11)
      4 = org.red5.server.net.rtmp.ReceivedMessageTask.call(ReceivedMessageTask.java:57)
      3 = org.red5.server.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPHandler.messageReceived(BaseRTMPHandler.java:105)
      2 = org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler.onCommand(RTMPHandler.java:293)
      1 = org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler.invokeCall(RTMPHandler.java:186)
      0 = org.red5.server.service.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:106)

  application = org.red5.server.service.ServiceNotFoundException
  description = Service not found: demoService
  code = NetConnection.Call.Failed
  level = error
```

I've also tried to use the very latest version of Red 5 but this returns the exact same error.

As for java, I've used:

```
yum -y install java-1.6.0-openjdk java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel
```

and

```
yum install java
```

Then for ant I just used

```
wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.8.2-bin.tar.gz
```

I know there will be newer versions of ant but I'm open to suggestions on what I could test.

I have Googled this plenty of times and I searched on here before I made this post. I seen a few attempts but since updates appear to affect red5, I'll use this post as a fresh updated version of hopefully tackling the problem.

I've noticed different sources suggest placing the applications into different paths each time

Thanks for your help.

Dev

Comment: Red5 no longer uses Ant to build, use Maven instead. There are pre-built releases here for red5: https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/releases

Comment: You may also find the wiki useful https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/wiki or this post especially https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/wiki/Installation-on-Linux

Comment: I manage to solve it, after about 20 hours! haha